# pattern matching in large dataset in r

Tags: r

I have dataframe in r with text column which has to broadly categorize into different column

```
Type                 Broader_Type
stiff clay           stiff clay
coarse sand          coarse sand
-
-
-
coasrse sand         coarse sand 
coasrse sand         coarse sand
COARSE               coarse sand
stiff clay           stiff clay  
marine clay          marine clay 
medium sand silt     medium sand
rock                 rock
hard strata          hard strata
type d above coarse  type D
medium sand with     medium sand
```

But there are spelling mistakes or some typo in observations. How can we do it in R and make it generalize ?

Comment: Sorry, Do you have the Broader_Type already or does it have to be created?

Comment: It has to be calculated.

Comment: I would have a look at fuzzy matching.

Comment: not sure how exactly but ```adist``` could help.